# Android Studio - XML image buttons and text won't fit the size

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

So, I am creating a workout app and getting problems with imageButtons and text.

[Screen-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lR6Qh.png)

content_app_layout_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context="hr.app.liftme.liftmehr.AppLayoutMain"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_app_layout_main"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/gornjiLayoutIkone"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonVjezbe"
            android:background="@drawable/ikona_vjezbe"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonProgramiTreninga"
            android:background="@drawable/ikona_programi"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:onClick="ProgramiTreninga"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonPopisTeretana"
            android:background="@drawable/ikona_popisteretana"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gornjiLayoutIkone"
        android:id="@+id/gornjiLayoutImena"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Vježbe"
            android:id="@+id/textViewVjezbe"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Programi \n treninga"
            android:id="@+id/textViewProgramiTreninga"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Popis \n teretana"
            android:id="@+id/textViewPopisTeretana"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gornjiLayoutImena"
        android:id="@+id/srednjiLayoutIkone"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonPrehrana"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ikona_prehrana" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonDodaciPrehrani"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ikona_dodaciprehrani" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonTrgovineSportskomPrehranom"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ikona_popistrgovina" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/srednjiLayoutIkone"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/srednjiLayoutImena">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Prehrana"
            android:id="@+id/textViewPrehrana"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Dodaci \n prehrani"
            android:id="@+id/textViewDodaciPrehrani"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Trgovine \n sportskom \n prehranom"
            android:id="@+id/textViewTrgovineSportskomPrehranom"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/srednjiLayoutImena"
        android:id="@+id/donjiLayoutIkone"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonSavjeti"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ikona_savjeti"
            android:onClick="Savjeti"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonKalkulatori"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ikona_kalkulatori" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonKontakt"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ikona_kontakt"
            android:onClick="Kontakt"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/donjiLayoutIkone"
        android:id="@+id/donjiLayoutImena">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Savjeti"
            android:id="@+id/textViewSavjeti"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Kalkulatori"
            android:id="@+id/textViewKalkulatori"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Kontakt"
            android:id="@+id/textViewKontakt"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

As you can see, main layout icons are OK, only text is not alligned properly. I don't know should I use layout:margin to align them, I think that won't be good because various screen sizes. Icons look good when there are exacly 3 in a row.

[Screen-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUGK1.png)

content_programi_treninga.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="hr.app.liftme.liftmehr.ProgramiTreninga"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_programi_treninga">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonProgramiBodybuilding"
            android:background="@drawable/ikona_programi_bodybuilding"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:onClick="ProgramiBodybuilding"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonProgramiPowerlifting"
            android:background="@drawable/ikona_programi_powerlifting"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:onClick="ProgramiPowerlifting"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Bodybuilding"
            android:id="@+id/textViewProgramiBodybuilding"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:onClick="ProgramiBodybuilding"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Powerlifting"
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:onClick="ProgramiPowerlifting"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="115dp"
            android:layout_height="115dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonPowerbuilding"
            android:background="@drawable/ikona_programi_powerbuilding"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:onClick="ProgramiPowerBuilding"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Power \nBuilding"
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see, it doesn't look good with 2 in a row.
I created various icon sizes, from ldpi screen to xxxhdpi screen and when I add them on my layout editor, they are so small so I am using layout:height to correct that. But I don't think that's a good idea because of different screen sizes.

So my question is, what should I do to fix this so it would be perfectly alligned and imageButtons big and in 1:1 ratio?

If you need me to upload some code, just tell me what code and I'll upload it ASAP!

Thanks!

Comment: Please never include your images. Post your code istead

Comment: Include the (xml)code for your layouts.

Comment: Its because of weight, it will assign equal width but height wont change, I think you can use grid view